# Looking for missing rows T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having an issue and I have been working on it for the past three hours or so and have not found a solution.  Running on a SQL Server platform.  I have a single table that looks like this.

```
PT   ITM  VAL
--   ---  ---
01   01   A
01   02   B
01   03   C
02   01   A
02   03   C
03   01   A
03   02   B
```

I am trying to find which PTs are missing the item numbers.

In the case above PT02 and PT03 are missing two item.  This is the base what where I started, but I am not sure if I am even on the right track.

```
select t.PT,t.ITM
FROM MYTABLE t
GROUP BY t.PT,t.ITM
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Thanks
jlimited

Comment: so there are only three ITMs for each PT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're expecting  3 ITM per PT, the query would be

```
select PT
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY PT
HAVING COUNT(ITM) < 3
```

for other conditions a more complicated query is required.

Comment: Thanks...that got me closer to what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here was the solution that worked.  I had to select a VAL that was populated, to find the values that were not.

```
select stg.PT,COUNT(stg.ITM) AS ITM_CNT
  FROM MYTABLE stg
 WHERE stg.ITM IS NOT NULL
   AND stg.VAL IN (11)
 GROUP BY stg.PT
HAVING COUNT(stg.ITM) > 1
EXCEPT
select stg.PT,COUNT(stg.ITM) AS ITM_CNT
  FROM MYTABLE stg
 WHERE stg.ITM IS NOT NULL
   AND stg.VLA IN (4,5)
 GROUP BY stg.PT
HAVING COUNT(stg.ITM) > 1
```